# CORS errors as a result of moving function into separate JS class

Tags: javascript

I have a button which sends an API bug report, however I recently moved it from Main.js into into its own class, and suddenly I receive CORS errors among others whenever I attempt to use it. I've done some research but I can't understand why this would be triggered simply by moving the function into its own class, looking for guidance as to why this behaviour might happen and how to avoid it.

Errors:

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.json is not a function
> Access to fetch at 'exampleUrl' from origin 'http://localhost:4567' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
> ```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

 $("#bugForm").submit((e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const input = document.getElementById('nameInput');
        // logic here
        const bugInfo = {
          info: "Hello"
        }
        Logger.logInfo(bugInfo).then(console.log('print'))
      })
    });
```

Logger.js

```
   class Logger {

   constructor(settings) {
   // getting the settings here and assigning it to the constructor variable
     this.settings = settings;
   }
   static async logInfo(data = {}) {
     console.log('Hello!')
     const url = 'https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/2530461/stories'
     const response = fetch(url, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         "Token": `${metadata.settings.token}}`,
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(data)
     });
     return response.json();
   }
 }

 const metadata = {
   settings: "Hello"
 }
 const logger = new Logger(metadata.settings);
```

Code before the move into new class:

```
 async function reportBug(data = {}) {
  const url = 'urlexample'
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "X-TrackerToken": `${metadata.settings.token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  return response.json();
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Moving the code doing an HTTP request to another class should not result in a CORS error. In addition to that, something else must have changed, like the code you used for fetching the data.

Comment: So you changed `"X-TrackerToken": \`${metadata.settings.token}\`` to `"Token": \`${metadata.settings.token}}\``. Why do you think that changing the header from `X-TrackerToken` to `Token`  is valid and not the reason for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this has most likely nothing to do with moving your function to another class.

But first of all, you are using `fetch` wrong

```
const response = fetch(url, { ...});
```

returns a promise. You have to wait until it resolves or rejects, until you can try accessing its body. Ie, you can't just do

```
return response.json()
```

because a `Promise` doesn't have a method `json()` (as the first error tells you). You have to either use `.then(...).catch(...)` or `await`. For instance

```
return fetch(...)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) //check if httpstatus is 2xx
      return response.json();

    throw new Error(`status ${response.status`);
  }
```

But be aware that this will also return a Promise (as `response.json()` is again async and returns a promise), which you have to wait for. And (at some) point you have to `.catch()` the errors from rejected promises (that's what the third error is telling you, your `fetch` ran into some error you are not catching) Grab one of the thousands of tutorials about async programming and rework your code.

The second error is telling you, that the answer from that server is missing a specific header definition from the `Access-Control-Allowed-Headers` header. (and that's most likely causing your `fetch` to fail). Ie you are sending a `Token` header to the server which is not allowed by the server. So, if you said it worked before moving the code, you probably didn't have that header before and added it shortly after moving the code. Although I'm not really sure, how that incorrect async programming would have worked ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll delve into async tutorials. The token however is the exact same token, and header as before, it hasn't been changed. Its just token and content-type. But there are minor changes to the async, ill post an edit.

Comment: In your original code the header is named `X-TrackerToken` which is probalby allowed by the server. After the move the header suddenly is named only `Token`. So, while it might by the same token, the header is named differently, which leads exactly to the error message you are seeing ...

Comment: A really obvious error! Thanks

Comment: Furthermore, before the move, your method was `async` and you correctly used `await`. After the move, the method is (for whatever reasons) not  `async` anymore. Thus, you coudn't use `await` anymore, therefore you decided to just ditch it. And thus, making the whole thing wrong